# how to load external page when change drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of keys to pass to external url to load inside div based on drop down change.Here I'm not able to append the key onload with below code. Please advise how to appended key on the url.
Code:

```
$("#key").on('change',function(){
    var widkey=$(this).val();
    $("#widgetpanel").html('<object id="webloader" data="http://localhost:8080/page"'+widkey+'>');
});
```

Comment: move the `"` like so:- `page'+widkey+'">`

Comment: Concatenation seems incorrect but there is not enough code context here either. Please provide a [mcve]